# Swift constant UIView never mutated warning

Tags: ios, swift

I was recently working on some test code, building silly view hierarchys and I ran across this little bit of code that made me squint a little extra hard.

```
var parentView: UIView = UIView()  //Warning here
parentView.addSubview(UIImageView())
```

On the first line is the following warning:

> Variable 'parentView' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

I'm confused as to why this element is not, or why the compiler believes it is not, being mutated.  I thought perhaps that Swift was detecting that a collection within the object was being mutated, and not the properties of the object itself.  This lead me to attempt the following:

```
let strings: [String] = []
strings.append("Hi") //This is an error
```

Given the above code, the only explanation I can come up with is that there is a bug somewhere.  Am I missing a keyword somewhere that allows this situation to make sense?  Something along the line's of C++'s "mutable" keyword?

If it's not a bug, I'd like to see this scenario re-created in a class that does not inherit from UIObject, so I can understand what causes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. For class instances (which are reference types), as e.g. your `UIView` instance, you may mutate instance properties even if the instance itself is a constant (`let)`. Arrays, on the other hand, are treated as value types in Swift, and members of a constant array (`let arr ...`) may not be mutated.

Hence, you never actually mutate `parentView` itself (`parentView = UIView()` would be a mutation of itself), only its members, and in such a case, it make sense (as the compiler notes) to mark `parentView` as a constant.

> If you create an instance of a structure and assign that instance to a
>   constant, *you cannot modify the instance’s properties, even if they
>   were declared as variable properties*:
>
> ...
>
> This behavior is due to *structures being value types. When an instance
>   of a value type is marked as a constant, so are all of its properties*.
>
> The same is *not true for classes, which are reference types*. If you
>   assign an instance of a reference type to a constant, *you can still
>   change that instance’s variable properties*.

From [Language Guide - Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254).

> ...
>
> You’ve actually been using value types extensively throughout the
>   previous chapters. In fact, all of the basic types in Swift—integers,
>   floating-point numbers, Booleans, strings, **arrays** and dictionaries—*are
>   value types, and are implemented as structures behind the scenes*.
>
> All structures and enumerations are value types in Swift. This means
>   that any structure and enumeration instances you create—and any value
>   types they have as properties—are always copied when they are passed
>   around in your code.

From [Language Guide - Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82).